# I do not see branches when cloning a repository

Tags: git

I am cloning a gitlab project on a new computer.

If i type "git branch", i only see master branch.

If i type "git branch -a", i see other branches in red with a "remotes/origin" prefix.

I can see what is in this branches by typing:

```
git checkout remotes/origin/mybranch
```

But i have seen this command on some tutorials:

```
git fetch origin mybranch:mybranch
```

In this case, mybranch will appear in "git branch" command, but i do not understand exactly what this command does. Branches have been already downloaded and fetched by first clone operation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly normal.

When you first clone some repository, you direct your Git to call up some other Git at some URL:

```
git clone <url>
```

Your Git starts out by creating a new, empty repository—this has no commits and no branches.  Then it sets up a *remote*—the name `origin`, normally, which records the URL you gave—and runs `git fetch`.  This fetch operation brings over all of the commits they have that you don't, which of course is just "all of the commits" since you don't have any yet.

At the end of the fetch process, your Git sets up all your *remote-tracking names*,<sup>1</sup> `origin/*`.  You get one such name for each branch name on the other Git.  Note that at this point, you still have no branch names of your own!

We can draw the commits and remote-tracking names in the usual way:

```
...--o--o--o   <-- origin/master
      \
       o--o   <-- origin/develop
```

and so on.  Each individual name points to one particular commit, the *tip* of the branch.

What you need to do in order to *add commits of your own* to one of these is to create your own branch name, pointing to one of these commits.  In fact, you have to do that just to be able to `git checkout somebranch`.  So the last thing `git clone` does is run:

```
git checkout master
```

(or perhaps some other name, depending on what you tell it to check out at the end).  This invokes a bit of magic.

Git looks through all of your own branch names, of which there are none.  It doesn't find `master`.  Instead of *complaining* and doing nothing, your Git goes on to look through all your *remote-tracking names*.  It looks for one that resembles `master`, and it finds exactly one: `origin/master`.  So your Git, at this point, *creates* the name `master`, and sets it to point to the *same* commit as `origin/master`:

```
...--o--o--o   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
      \
       o--o   <-- origin/develop
```

Now that the name `master` exists, `git checkout` can check it out, and now you're on branch `master`.

None of the other `origin/*` names has been used ... *yet*.  But if you now run:

```
git checkout develop
```

your Git goes through the same process: there is no `develop`, so it looks through all your remote-tracking names and finds `origin/develop`.  It then says to itself: *Aha, you must want me to create `develop` pointing to the same commit as `origin/develop`, and then switch to `develop`!*  So it does that:

```
...--o--o--o   <-- master, origin/master
      \
       o--o   <-- develop (HEAD), origin/develop
```

In these drawings, I attach the word `HEAD` to the current, checked-out branch.  Git does the same thing internally: that's how Git knows which branch you're on, and which branch name to modify when adding new commits.

Note that there's no need to *create* a new branch name until you want to *add commits to it*.  You can check out a specific commit by its hash ID, or you can use `git checkout origin/develop` instead of `git checkout develop`.  This gives you what Git calls a *detached HEAD:*

```
...--o--o--o   <-- master, origin/master
      \
       o--o   <-- HEAD, origin/develop
```

Now `HEAD` points directly to a commit, instead of marking a branch-name and letting the branch-name point to the commit.  That's OK up until you make *new* commits; then you probably want to have a branch name to remember the latest such commit.

---

<sup>1</sup>It's disputable as to whether these are also considered "branch names."  They are certainly *names*, and they identify the tips of structural branches within the commit graph.  But the two-word phrase *remote branches*, which some people use as a way to refer to these, is a misleading name.  They're names in *your* Git repository!  Git calls them *remote-tracking branch names*, which uses the combined string of words *remote* + *tracking* + *branch* in a way that's *different* from the other ways that Git uses each individual word.  It's no wonder people find Git maddening.

Answer (score 0):

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch:

> `<refspec>`
>
> Specifies which refs to fetch and which local refs to update. When no `<refspec>`s appear on the command line, the refs to fetch are read from `remote.<repository>.fetch` variables instead (see CONFIGURED REMOTE-TRACKING BRANCHES below).
>
> The format of a `<refspec>` parameter is an optional plus +, followed by the source `<src>`, followed by a colon :, followed by the destination ref `<dst>`. The colon can be omitted when `<dst>` is empty. `<src>` is typically a ref, but it can also be a fully spelled hex object name.
>
> `tag <tag>` means the same as `refs/tags/<tag>:refs/tags/<tag>`; it requests fetching everything up to the given tag.
>
> The remote ref that matches `<src>` is fetched, and if `<dst>` is not empty string, the local ref that matches it is fast-forwarded using `<src>`. If the optional plus + is used, the local ref is updated even if it does not result in a fast-forward update.

So this command: fetches `mybranch` from remote `origin`; fast-forwards the local `mybranch` to the fetched one. So

> > mybranch will appear in "git branch" command

because there's now a local `mybranch`.

> Branches have been already downloaded and fetched by first clone operation

But no local branches (other than the default one, usually `master`) are created.

Comment: I do not really understand the difference between remote and local branches. In my case, the branches are downloaded when i clone. Does that mean i cannot change anything to "remote" branch and i should fetch it in order to make it local ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "the branches are downloaded when i clone". You _can_ make changes without creating local branches, but it's inconvenient; instead, you'd normally do `git branch mybranch`, not that long `fetch` command.

Comment: In fact i do not understand the difference between "remotes/origin/mybranch" and "mybranch" branches

Comment: Have you read https://git-scm.com/book/id/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches?